# Can MaskFormatter take any size, or only the size you provide?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, maskformatter

I would like to limit my input to my `JFormattedTextField`, and I have a setup that uses `MaskFormatter`.

However, I must put in the number of characters I specify (in this case 5). Is there a way I can have it accept any size input and still limit my input to just lowercase characters? Or should I be using a different class for my purpose?

Below is what I currently have.

My goal is to have two text box inputs and compare the texts input between them.

```
//This formatter allows for up to a 10 character word.
    //No spaces allowed.
    MaskFormatter leftMask = null;
    try {
        leftMask = new MaskFormatter("LLLLL");
        leftMask.setInvalidCharacters("1234567890 ");
        leftMask.setOverwriteMode(false);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MaskFormatter rightMask = null;
    try {
        rightMask = new MaskFormatter("LLLLL");
        rightMask.setInvalidCharacters("1234567890 ");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Initialize components
    leftTextField = new JFormattedTextField(leftMask);
    rightTextField = new JFormattedTextField(rightMask);
    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");

    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
           InputReader reader = new InputReader();
           result.setText("These two strings are:");
           if(reader.readInput(leftTextField.getText(), rightTextField.getText())){
               result.append(" a match");
           }
           else{
               result.append(" not a match");
           }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you could write a method which did something like...

```
public static String generateFormat(char with, int count) {
    return String.format("%" + count + "s", "").replaceAll(" ", Character.toString(with));
}
```

Basically, what this will allow you to do is generate a `String` filled with the value of `with` to the `count` of characters, something like...

```
leftMask = new MaskFormatter(generateFormat('L', 5));
```

Now, this is not a perfect solution and a better solution might be to use a `DocumentFilter` which will give you complete control over how much and what the user can enter, in real time...

Have a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details.

Comment: So, although this method works, MaskFormatter still requires the input to be all 5 (or what ever number you choose) characters. If it isn't, it just doesn't take the input. My thing is that it should take the input regardless of it is the maximum amount of characters or not. I will also be looking at the links you provided. Thanks for the response!

Comment: That's why I'd dump the formatted field and use a JTextField and use a DocumentFilter